# Pass a variable to a function from a string (python)

Tags: python

I am quite new to the programming world and I would need some advice.

I am constructing a "test you knowledge" program.

I determine the answers based on the index of the question. Each question has its answer on the same index.

But I have a specific case in which I need to print a list of answers from which the user will have to select the correct one, which also corresponds to the index of the question.

I select a question from a list:

```py
question = random.choice(listeQuestions)
```

I identify the index of the question:

```py
indexQuestion = listeQuestions.index(str(question))
```

I have the type of question in my question string, so when 'QCM' appears I know that I need to print a list.

I need to print the list of possible answers from a list corresponding to the index of the question:

```py
if 'QCM' in question:
  option ='option'+str(indexQuestion)
  printList(option)
  answer = input()
  reponseSimple(answer,indexReponse)
```

For example, if my question has index number 8, I want to pass the variable "option8" to my function `printList(option)`.

```py
def printList(option):
    for i in range(len(option)):
        print(option[i])
```

If the index is 8, I would like to call the list option8 that is predefined and pass it to my function as `printList(option8)`.

Here I try to build the variable by building a string. But it does not work.

Any idea on how I could do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant parts of your actual code?

Comment: Sounds like you want a list of lists, called `options`, so that e.g. `options[8]` will be the list you currently call `option8`.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I do not want to call a list of list. Just the list called "option8" which contains the different answers to be printed. There are several lists: option1, option3, option8 in this program and I identify which list is to be printed based on the index of the question.

Comment: identifying something by an index is best done by putting it in a list (you can use a dict as well...), and accessing the list by index. the "something" you want to identify is a list, hence, you want a list of lists. QED.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Thanks for your help. My problem here is that the index my question does not correspond to the index of the list of option that I want to print. It corresponds to the name of the list directly --> the list name would option8 if the index of my question is 8.

Comment: in the line of code where you wanted to put down `option8`, you can use `options[8]` to index into a list containing the same value that `option8` has, given that you put it there. If this still doesn't make sense to you, I would advise revisiting some tutorial on python lists.

Comment: @rleclere Try to imagine what it would be to have 1000 questions, you do not want 1000 variables with a name for each one, however a list with 1000 items is common in programming, and it will allow you to scale easily.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to link metadata to each question so that you know what to ask the user. This can be done using dictionaries :

```py
import random
listQuestions = [
    {
        "question": "What is the capital of France?",
        "type": "QCM",
        "options": ["Paris", "London", "Berlin", "Madrid"],
        "answer": "Paris"
    },
    {
        "question": "What is the capital of Germany?",
        "type": "exact",
        "answer": "Berlin"
    }
]

def askQuestion(question):
    # Ask the question
    print(question["question"])
    # Check the question type
    if question["type"] == "QCM":
        # Print out all the options
        for i in range(len(question["options"])):
            print(f"{i+1}. {question['options'][i]}")
        # Ask the user for an answer
        answer = input("Your answer: ")
        # Convert the answer to the corresponding option
        return question["options"][int(answer)-1] # This needs a try/except block
    elif question["type"] == "exact":
        return input("Your answer: ")

def main():
    question = random.choice(listQuestions)
    answer = askQuestion(question)
    if answer == question["answer"]:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print(f"Wrong! The correct answer was {question['answer']}")

main() # Call the main function
```

Here, each question contains a few fields :

- The actual question
- Its type (QCM or exact) you can add more types to your liking
- The expected answer
- For the QCM type, the options available

Using this you can pack the data in a list in a human-readable format and use it in your code easily.

If you have a strong requirement on storing the questions as string, I would recommend using the `json` module to serialize/deserialize your data :

```py
import python
questionStr = json.dumps(question)
question = json.loads(questionStr)
```